# SQL Indexing when full joining two tables on columns that might be NULL

Tags: sql, indexing, non-clustered-index, full-join

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`, both with columns `group`, `element_id1`, `element_id2`, `date`.
For every `date` and every `group`, there are multiple elements in the group. Each element has 2 ids (every `element_id1` is mapped to exactly one `element_id2` as vice versa, but sometimes one of them can be `NULL` [exists but not recorded in our table for that row]).
I want to find elements that are in one table per each `group` and `date` but not in the other. For checking if two elements are equal, I match them either on `element_id1` or `element_id2` (depending on which one is non-`NULL`).
For example let the tables be:

- **table1:**

| group | element_id1 | element_id2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 1 | NULL | 1/31/2024 |
| G1 | 2 | B | 1/31/2024 |
| G1 | 3 | C | 1/31/2024 |
| G1 | NULL | A | 2/2/2024 |
| G1 | 4 | D | 2/2/2024 |
| G2 | 1 | A | 1/31/2024 |
| G2 | 5 | NULL | 2/2/2024 |

- **table2:**

| group | element_id1 | element_id2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 1 | A | 1/31/2024 |
| G1 | NULL | B | 1/31/2024 |
| G1 | NULL | A | 2/2/2024 |
| G1 | 4 | NULL | 2/2/2024 |
| G2 | 1 | A | 1/31/2024 |
| G2 | NULL | F | 2/2/2024 |

I want the outcome to be

| group | element_id1 | element_id2 | date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 3 | C | 1/31/2024 | Missing from table2 |
| G2 | 5 | NULL | 2/2/2024 | Missing from table2 |
| G2 | NULL | F | 2/2/2024 | Missing from table1 |

I want to set INDEX in the tables. What are the good indices here? Should I index on the combination of (`group`, `date`, `element_id1`, `element_id2`)? But the problem is sometimes one of the `elemet_id`s is `NULL`. Sould I index only on group and date in both tables?

The SQL that I use is as follows but is VERY slow:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.group, t2.group) as [Group],
       COALESCE(t1.element_id1, t2.element_id1) as element_id1,
       COALESCE(t1.element_id2, t2.element_id2) as element_id2,
       COALESCE(t1.[date], t2.[date]) as [date],
       CASE WHEN t1.[date] IS NULL THEN 'Missing from table1'
            ELSE 'Missing from table2'
       END AS [Status]
FROM
       table1 t1
FULL JOIN
       table2 t2
ON     t1.[group] = t2.[group]
       AND t1.[date] = t2.[date]
       AND (t1.element_id1 = t2.element_id1 OR t1.element_id2 = t2.element_id2)
WHERE t1.[date] IS NULL OR t2.[date] IS NULL
```

Comment: `AND t1.[date] = t1.[date]` ?

Comment: Fixed. My bad when re-writing it. I was trying to make it simple in the question and re-wrote the problem.

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0):

The OR condition is what's going to be the limitation.

Optimisations for that can be to split the query and UNION ALL the results, or to invert the logic and use AND instead of OR.

For example;

```
SELECT
  *, 'Missing from T2'
FROM
  T1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM T2
     WHERE T2.group       = T1.group
       AND T2.[date]      = T1.[date]
       AND T2.element_id1 = T1.element_id1
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM T2
     WHERE T2.group       = T1.group
       AND T2.[date]      = T1.[date]
       AND T2.element_id2 = T1.element_id2
  )

UNION ALL

SELECT
  *, 'Missing from T1'
FROM
  T2
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM T1
     WHERE T1.group       = T2.group
       AND T1.[date]      = T2.[date]
       AND T1.element_id1 = T2.element_id1
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM T1
     WHERE T1.group       = T2.group
       AND T1.[date]      = T2.[date]
       AND T1.element_id2 = T2.element_id2
  )
```

Then both tables should have two indexes each:

- `(group, [date], element_id1)`
- `(group, [date], element_id2)`

That's a lot of code repetition, but it's also an unusual table setup and requirement.